# Copy multiple rows from one worksheet to another worksheet using macro/vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I've looked around the forum and played with various options but not found a clear match for my problem:

My task is to copy data from a worksheet (called “workorders”) to a second worksheet (called “Assignments”).  The data to be copied is from the “workorders” worksheet starting at cell range “E2, P2:S2”; and also copied from each row (same range) until column “P” is empty – (the number of rows to be copied can vary each time we need to run this macro so we can’t select a standard range) .  Then pasted into the “Assignments” worksheet, starting at cell “A4”.  I’ve used the forum so far to successfully copy a single row of date (from row 2) – I admit that’s the easy part, and I’ve used various versions of code to achieve this.
I’ve also tried some code (which I found via watching a youtube clip and modifying  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PyNWL0DXXtQ )to allow me to run a loop which repeats the copy process for each required row in the “workorders” worksheet  and then pastes the data into the “assignments” worksheet- but this is where I am not getting it right, I think I’m along the right lines and think I’m not far off but any help would be very useful.

Code examples below (first 2 only copy first row, 3rd example is where I’ve tried to loop and copy multiple rows:

```
Sub CopyTest1()
' CopyTest1 Macro
'copy data from workorders sheet
'Worksheets("workorders").Range("E2,P2,Q2,R2,S2").Copy
Worksheets("workorders").Range("E2, P2:S2").Copy
'paste data to assignments sheet
'sheets("assigments dc").Range("A4").Paste
Sheets("Assigments DC").Select
Range("A4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub




Sub CopyTest2()
Sheets("workorders").Range("e2,p2,q2,r2,s2").Copy Sheets("assigments dc").Range("a4")
End Sub


Sub CopyTest3()
Dim xrow As Long
'Dim xrow As String
xrow = 2
Worksheets("workorders").Select
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 16).End(xlUp).Row
Do Until xrow = lastrow + 1
ActiveSheet.Cells(xrow, 16).Select
If ActiveCell.Text = Not Null Then
'Range("E2,P2,Q2,R2,S2").Copy
'Selection = Range("E2,P2,Q2,R2,S2").Copy
'Cells(xrow, 5).Copy
Cells(xrow, 5).Copy
Sheets("Assigments DC").Select
Range("A4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("workorders").Select
End If
xrow = xrow + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub LoopCopy()

    Dim shWO As Worksheet, shAss As Worksheet
    Dim WOLastRow As Long, Iter As Long
    Dim RngToCopy As Range, RngToPaste As Range

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set shWO = .Sheets("Workorders") 'Modify as necessary.
        Set shAss = .Sheets("Assignments") 'Modify as necessary.
    End With

    'Get the row index of the last populated row in column P.
    'Change accordingly if you want to use another column as basis.
    'Two versions of getting the last row are provided.
    WOLastRow = shWO.Range("P2").End(xlDown).Row
    'WOLastRow = shWO.Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Iter = 2 to WOLastRow
        Set RngToPaste = shAss.Range("A" & (Iter + 2))
        With shWO
            Set RngToCopy = Union(.Range("E" & Iter), .Range("P" & Iter & ":S" & Iter))
            RngToCopy.Copy RngToPaste
        End With
    Next Iter

End Sub
```

Read the comments first and test.

Let us know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you are only copying the cell in Column E.  You could correct this by replacing `Cells(xrow, 5).Copy` with

```
Union(Sheets("workorders").Cells(xrow,5),Sheets("workorders").Range(Cells(xrow,"P"),Cells(xrow,"S")).Copy
```

However, using `Select` and `Copy` are not ideal.  Instead, you can assign the value of the range directly:

```
Sheets("Assignments DC").Range("A4").Value = Union(Sheets("workorders").Cells(xrow,5),Sheets("workorders").Range(Cells(xrow,"P"),Cells(xrow,"S")).Value
```

More info on [the Union method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213609%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and [why using Select is bad](http://www.businessprogrammer.com/power-excel-vba-secret-avoid-using-select/).

Answer (score 0):

Is it even possible to run a line like this?
Worksheets("workorders").Range("E2, P2:S2").Copy

Each time I try different ways to copy/select a range which contains in my case, A3 and the range A34:C40 ("A3, A34:C40").Copy i get an error saying theres to many parameters.. Could this be because I'm running excel 2007?

Any tips or help would be greatly apreciated! :)