# Excel VBA - How to copy rows based on a criteria from multiplesheets into one sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I've have a spreadsheet with multiple sheets and a need to copy specific rows based on a criteria (a specific month). So the idea is to be able to loop through the other sheets and copy rows (for example all rows with June in column 1) onto the sheet "Consolidated Data" from all the country files without touching  the "Do not include" sheet.

[image: Budgeting Pic]

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy multiple rows from one worksheet to another worksheet using macro/vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098265/copy-multiple-rows-from-one-worksheet-to-another-worksheet-using-macro-vba)

Comment: Hi Simon, different request as I need to loop through worksheets as well

Comment: Ah. My apologies then! Hopefully that link will help get you started at least

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more specific - do all the country pages look the same? How are you indicating the criteria (i.e. June), and what do you want the consolidated data tab to look like?

Comment: Yes sorry the country pages look the same I.e. the columns have all the same headers but the exact location of the rows may not be the same. Meaning I may have 10 rows of data containing June in the first column for country 1 but 9 for country 2. The consolidated data tab is formatted the exact same way as countries but I want the copy paste to be sequential like country 1 Then country 2. Hope this clarifies, thanks!